# Add simple keywords to index using glossaries (skdoc)

Tags: glossaries, indexing, package-writing

I am writing a package using `skdoc`, which uses `glossaries` to create the index listing commands, environments etc. automatically.

Now, I want to add some keywords to the index manually (and simple), like it's done with `\index` at `makeidx`.

Is there any functionality of `glossaries` or `skdoc` like this?

```
\documentclass{skdoc}

\SelfPreambleTo{\mypreamble}
\DeclareFile[key=package,preamble=\mypreamble]{test.sty}
\OnlyDescription


\begin{document}

  \package{test}
  \author{Homer Simpson}
  \email{homer@springfield.com}

  \maketitle
  \begin{abstract}
    The \thepackage\ package provides some stuff.
  \end{abstract}

  \section{Documentation}

  % !!! HERE I WANT TO INDEX A KEYWORT !!!
  Explain some stuff about keyword\index{keyword}.

  \DescribeMacro\yeah
  Describe macro here.

  \Implementation
  \section{Implementation}

\begin{MacroCode}{package}
\ProvidesExplPackage{test}
    {2017/05/03}{1.0}{Some things about donuts}
\end{MacroCode}


  \begin{macro}{\yeah}
\begin{MacroCode}{package}
\RenewDocumentCommand\yeah{ }{%
  Yeah!
}
\end{MacroCode}
  \end{macro}


\begin{MacroCode}{package}
\endinput
\end{MacroCode}

    \Finale
    \PrintChanges
    \PrintIndex
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `skdoc` class generates a glossary called `index`, so you can use `glossaries` commands to achieve what you want.

That is, to add `keyword` to the index, you can declare in your preamble:

```
\newglossaryentry{keyword}{type=index,name={keyword},description=\nopostdesc}
```

and use `\gls{keyword}` instead of simply writing `keyword` when needed.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{skdoc}

\newglossaryentry{keyword}{type=index,name={keyword},description=\nopostdesc}

\SelfPreambleTo{\mypreamble}
\DeclareFile[key=package,preamble=\mypreamble]{test.sty}
\OnlyDescription


\begin{document}

  \package{test}
  \author{Homer Simpson}
  \email{homer@springfield.com}

  \maketitle
  \begin{abstract}
    The \thepackage\ package provides some stuff.
  \end{abstract}

  \section{Documentation}

  % !!! HERE I WANT TO INDEX A KEYWORT !!!
  Explain some stuff about \gls{keyword}.

  \DescribeMacro\yeah
  Describe macro here.

  \Implementation
  \section{Implementation}

\begin{MacroCode}{package}
\ProvidesExplPackage{test}
    {2017/05/03}{1.0}{Some things about donuts}
\end{MacroCode}


  \begin{macro}{\yeah}
\begin{MacroCode}{package}
\RenewDocumentCommand\yeah{ }{%
  Yeah!
}
\end{MacroCode}
  \end{macro}


\begin{MacroCode}{package}
\endinput
\end{MacroCode}

    \Finale
    \PrintChanges
    \PrintIndex
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Alternatively, you can define a new command `\myindex`

```
\newcommand{\myindex}[1]{%
  \newglossaryentry{#1}{type=index,name={#1},description=\nopostdesc}%
  \glsadd{#1}}
```

to be used just like `\index`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{skdoc}

\newcommand{\myindex}[1]{%
  \newglossaryentry{#1}{type=index,name={#1},description=\nopostdesc}%
  \glsadd{#1}}

\SelfPreambleTo{\mypreamble}
\DeclareFile[key=package,preamble=\mypreamble]{test.sty}
\OnlyDescription


\begin{document}

  \package{test}
  \author{Homer Simpson}
  \email{homer@springfield.com}

  \maketitle
  \begin{abstract}
    The \thepackage\ package provides some stuff.
  \end{abstract}

  \section{Documentation}

  % !!! HERE I WANT TO INDEX A KEYWORT !!!
  Explain some stuff about keyword\myindex{keyword}.

  \DescribeMacro\yeah
  Describe macro here.

  \Implementation
  \section{Implementation}

\begin{MacroCode}{package}
\ProvidesExplPackage{test}
    {2017/05/03}{1.0}{Some things about donuts}
\end{MacroCode}


  \begin{macro}{\yeah}
\begin{MacroCode}{package}
\RenewDocumentCommand\yeah{ }{%
  Yeah!
}
\end{MacroCode}
  \end{macro}


\begin{MacroCode}{package}
\endinput
\end{MacroCode}

    \Finale
    \PrintChanges
    \PrintIndex
\end{document}
```

The output is the same as above.

Comment: Thanks Karl! I forgot to mention, that I already know this. But I am searching for a way to index the keyword "inline" (like \index does).

Comment: @dawu Why do you want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Because it is more comfortable only to call \index? Additionally, I don't have a description (for which reason it is not a "real" glossary entry). I am not looking for a complex answer or workaround, but hoped, that I missed a simple solution.

Comment: @dawu see the addition in the answer.